# Can the file I want to import into an application in Archer be encrypted? Or I need to decrypt it before importing?

Tags: encryption, import, archer

I need to create a new package in Archer but before I need to import data into an application which is part of a solution.
Can the file I want to import into an application in Archer RSA be encrypted? Or I need to decrypt it before importing? Will this affect my data ingestion?

PS: If I have 5 files, for different locations, how should I proceed?

Thank you. I'm still learning Archer